# Concatenate in php inside HTML

Tags: php, html

i am unable to concatenate i am not so good at it wondering how would i concatenate in this scenario

```
<?php   $id = getfield('id'); ?>// this is a function to get fields from sql

<html>
    <?php <a class="profile" href="profile.php?='$id' ">
<echo ucfirst ($firstname);</a> ?>//i cant seem to get this part
    </html>
```

This is what i have tried so far i did try some other ways to do it but none of them seem to work

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.concat.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you are looking for:

```
<?php $id = getfield('id'); ?> // this is a function to get fields from sql

<html>
    <a class="profile" href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>">
        <?php echo ucfirst ($firstname) ?>
    </a>
</html>
```

Or, more compact if you have "short tags" enabled inside php:

```
<?php $id = getfield('id'); ?> // this is a function to get fields from sql

<html>
    <a class="profile" href="profile.php?id=<?= $id ?>">
        <?= ucfirst ($firstname) ?>
    </a>
</html>
```

And finally you could inline the assignment, since the variable is used only once:

```
<html>
    <a class="profile" href="profile.php?id=<?= getfield('id') ?>">
        <?= ucfirst ($firstname) ?>
    </a>
</html>
```

Comment: i am really bad in concatenate

Comment: @jake123 Glad I could help. Note however that the issue has nothing to do with concatenation. It was an issue with using php tags correctly. But great that you sorted things out now!

Comment: Why whould you close and open php tags twice, instead of doing everything in a single echo ?

Comment: thanks again sir you have been really help full
i see the solution is not that difficult but i could not get it write i will keep this in mind next time thanks

Comment: @Nirnae Both is possible, this is a question of personal taste. Most people consider the style above to be easier to read. Echoing html markup is somewhat frowned upon in general, though it certainly is possible from a technical point of view.

Comment: @Nirnae 
i have just started php thanks for pointing out what i did wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick :

```
<?php
  $id = getfield('id'); // this is a function to get fields from sql


    echo '<html>
             <a class="profile" href="profile.php?='.$id.' ">'.ucfirst ($firstname).'</a>
         </html>';
?>
```